# How do I permanently remove Google Docs from my Drive?

Tags: google-docs, delete

I am very confused. After searching for the answer all over the internet, I've seemed to wind up here. How do you actually delete files from google docs? After pressing remove, I wait 10-15 seconds before going to my "Trash" on Google Drive. The documents never seem to show up, and they end up just reappearing on Docs. These were shared to me by someone else over the course of the last year, and I'd estimate there's around 130 of them. I've even gone directly to Google Drive and have deleted them (along with other types of files in the same selection), but they never show up in the trash. This would be on a Mac or Chromebook if possible. No one seems to ask this question directly. I'd really appreciate some help.

Thanks,
S. I.